# How do I run a Gradle project in eclipse as a Java Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I've created a very simple Gradle java project in eclipse. I'm able to run the main file (which just outputs text) by using the 'run' application command in the Gradle tasks section, but when I right-click on the project and select 'Run as a java application' I get a very generic Eclipse error that just says 'Launch Error'with no explanation. Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Why am I able to run it through the gradle tasks command but not through eclipse?

[The error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twrrb.png)

[The very simple code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxIoD.png)

Comment: I think , you cannot do it..You can only run a java application if you create it as a java application in eclipse but you have created it as gradle app..You can right click and run as gradle task thats all..

Comment: Do you get the same results when you right-click on the *class* and select "Run as Java application"?

Comment: I get the same result. In the tutorial that I watched the bloke had no problem.